# What do you call this part of the sentence that describes a quotation in a dialog?

Tags: word-request, sentence-structure, commas, quotations

In this dumb example:

> — I can hardly find a good example, **he said**.
>   — I know, **she answered,** I can hardly find one too.

What do you call the bold parts of the sentences, which describe how the character is speaking?

I've found many questions/answers about the use of a comma before a quotation, nothing related to the name of the part of the sentence introduced by a comma *after* a quotation, especially inside a dialog.

If I translate the french word for this in english, it should be a *parenthetical element*. But in all I've read so far, parenthetical elements never appear in dialogs (I mean in the construction of the dialog, since a character can pronounce a sentence with a parenthetical element, that's not the question).

EDIT: The french word is *incise*. Sorry I forgot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is called the *reporting clause*

> [Reported speech: reporting and reported clauses](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech)
>   Speech reports consist of two parts: the ***reporting clause*** and the reported clause. The ***reporting clause*** includes a verb such as say, tell, ask, reply, shout, usually in the past simple, and the reported clause includes what the original speaker said.

Comment: @Arcesilas I studied some French... I never thought it would be handy xD